# How to measure power dissipation through each component in PCB board?

Tags: pcb, power-dissipation

I have designed an RF based PCB board and for testing purpose I would like to measure the power dissipation through each component.

Someone suggested, by measuring the temperature of each component one can get the power dissipation. Is it a reliable solution ? Are there any other ways to measure that?

Comment: Why do you need to measure each component?

Comment: The component temperate will rise until power losses (through radiation, conduction and convection) equals the electrical power into the component. You cannot easily calculate power from temperature unless you know all the factors. (You could study how to do a heatsink sizing calculation for information on this.) You don't say *why* you want to do this. If you just want to staty within ratings then temperature *would* be a good simple check as it will show you any hotspots.

Comment: To know which component is drawing how much power, so that helps me whether a particular component is dissipating more than nominal. Just for testing purpose

Comment: just use a temp probe. or your finger. if you can hold it it on tight without pain, that's good. Then time duration is an indicator or need for more thermal vias et cetera

Comment: Is it that there is no other option than measuring the temperature ?

Comment: FLIR camera maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends why you want to know.

If you want to verify that your simulations are an accurate representation of your design, then measuring voltages at various nodes would be better.

If you want to establish that none of your components are going to fail too early from over-dissipation, then you want the temperature, not the power dissipation *per se*.

When a component is rated at (say) 250mW average, it's an estimate, by the manufacturer, of what power can be dissipated long term, with a guess at how the end user (you) has got it configured on the board, while keeping the hottest part of the component below some critical temperature.

As the user, you have the luxury of not having to guess how it's soldered, to what size heatsink, with what airflow, with how big a solder fillet. You can just plain measure the temperature! Measure the case, the hotspots, the surroundings, and compare those with the maximum temperatures the manufacturer gives for reliability.

Answer (score 0):

At the level of physics, temperature is NOT a good indication of heat
dissipation, because dissimilar metals carrying current do heat pumping
(Peltier effect).   If you can ignore that kind of effect (you usually
can) then the problem is just as easy as modeling the thermal conductivity
of all your materials, joints, and accounting for convective flow and
radiation moving heat around.   Which is to say, it's harder to know
heat than to measure temperature.